# GreenDao, how delete relationship entity

Tags: android, greendao

I have EntityA and EntityB. EntityA has a to-many relationship with EntityB.

I have several EntityB objects that have been set as related (children) to EntityA. How can I delete that relationship without deleting any of the Entity objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
EntityB entityB = myEntityBDao.load(id_entityB);
entityB.setEntityA(null);
entityB.update();
```

This just deletes the relation and modifies entityB, but a formerly related EntityA should not be deleted or even modified.

Comment: is this really possible? can we delete the relationship without deleting the item? @AlexS